# Simplifying $\sum_{n=1}^{x}ne^{-a}\frac{a^{x-n}}{(x-n)!}$, where $x$ is an integer and $a<1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I would like to simplify the following expression,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{x}ne^{-a}\frac{a^{x-n}}{(x-n)!}$$

where $x$ is an integer and $a<1$.

Is it possible to lose the sum?

An approximation for the sum will be also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It can be written using the Incomplete Gamma function as
$$ {\frac {{{\rm e}^{-a}}{a}^{x}-\Gamma \left( x,a \right)  \left( a-x
 \right) }{\Gamma \left( x \right) }}
$$

Comment: Thanks @Robert Israel, but I was thinking maybe there is a simpler option, without using the Gamma.

Comment: can you please show how you get to the term?